# Active model serializer, render association without key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have a table named featured_products witch contains only two columns (product_id, position).
On my GET /featured_products, I want to render something like this

```
[
   { "name":"Product 1" }
   { "name":"product 2" }
]
```

But instead, I logically get this:

```
[
   "product":{ "name":"Product 1" }
   "product":{ "name":"product 2" }
]
```

Following the doc of Active Model Serializers, I'v tried these in my featured_product serializer class:

```
embed_in_root: true
```

and

```
belongs_to :product, embed_in_root: true
```

but the first on gives an error while second changes the JSON in no way.

I don't know if I missed the answer I'm looking for in Active Model Serializer's doc or if the answer is to be found elsewhere, but I didn't manage to solve this on my own, I'd be happy to get some advices here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
render json: FeaturedProduct.includes(:product).order(:position).map(&:product) # include :product to avoid N + 1 queries on products
```

Comment: Here again, it works for my specific case. Out of curiosity, is there anyway to "include" the product in my JSON while still serializing it in FeaturedProductSerializer to include other stuff (like Position in my case) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a solution which does work for my specific case.

Since for every featured_product, I only want to display the product associated, I ended up mapping this in the render call.

ie, I went from that

```
render json: FeaturedProduct.all.order(:position)
```

to that

```
render json: FeaturedProduct.all.order(:position).map(&:product)
```

This way, the serializer of Product is called and not the one from FeaturedProduct.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
render json: @products, root: false
```